# Is there any hadoop implement of Louvain method?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

This is louvain method to find community in social graph.
https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/
I want to run it on a big graph.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not stuck on Hadoop, I saw this implementation for Apach Spark.
https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an implementation of this clustering method, which looks to be based on modularity. The main source of clustering algorithms in the Hadoop ecosystem is in Mahout.

Take a look here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Algorithms

Perhaps one of the clustering algorithms listed would work or provide the basis for your own implementation.